# Angular pass data to an imported module

Tags: angular, service, module

I have an issue concerning the way I should pass data to imported module in my App.

Actually, I have created a module which contains many components that I use in my app.

I would like to give this module two data objects User and Company.

The problem is that I don't want to pass them as input in each component, I feel it's redundant in my module I'll have to deal with inputs everywhere with the same object.

What I want is to pass those two objects to my imported module, and being able to have them in a shared service to use them all around the module.

I know I can pass config object using forRoot(). But in my case, I'm not sure it's made for this purpose (pass two data object). And also if the user didn't logged in yet I think the object will be null and won't be updated later.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you show in code what you have tried?

Comment: What exactly you want to see ? because I didn't yet tried anything as I mentioned the two solution I was thinking about and why I wouldn't or couldn't do it.
I can show the module architecture complexity ?!

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here is to create a basic services that holds your 2 data objects.
Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  user: User;
  company: Company;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Each component that wants this data has to inject the service and retreive the data.

```
user: User;
company: Company;

constructor(private testservice: TestService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.testservice.user;
  this.company = this.testservice.company;
}
```

If however you need to push updates from 1 component to another you should use Subjects in the service instead of the plain object. Click [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) for more info about this.